# lucene search performance is very slow

Tags: lucene.net

I am using lucene.net, I need to index and store very large size of document say 500 GB, Creates index folder of size 500 GB  When I use search on this it tooks too much time say 10 min, I use analyzed and not analyzed Index type on different Fields , I have 90 such different fields.
                Please help me.                                                              Pravin Thokal

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have 90 fields that are index fields?

Comment: yes , most of the are having small data very few have large data

Comment: That is a huge key, sounds kind of weird to me. Those are a lot of indices, you should consider taking it down to less than 20.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I will minimize my field count to less than 20, I would like to ask you one another question I would like to provide Normal and Regular Expression Search to users using lucene.net ,I Index and store the document in Analyzed and Not Analyzed way to support both search type,that means I need to index and store document twice , is there any way so that I can index and store docs only once and can use for both search types ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932667/index-analyzed-and-not-analyzed

Comment: Are you really saying that you're _storing_ 500 gb worth of data? That would create a huge index, thus making it hard to use in-memory caches. Have you checked your performance counters during search? What's your io usage (disk read bytes per sec, disk io per sec and disk queue length)?

Comment: By the time I will provide you detail statistics, Can you tell me what will be the best approach for indexing ?